# Uber Driver app using too much resources

Tags: applications, battery, battery-life, cpu, uber

So, I'm working a bit as a bicycle courier for Uber Eats. For this, I have to use their app Uber Driver.

Problem is, my phone battery (which still holds charge well) is draining very, very fast when using that application. It can run only a handful of hours. Furthermore, discharging/recharging the battery that much would quickly impact its lifespan...

So I have to carry several powerbanks and always have one connected...

It would be so better if the app could just use less resources. Probably some things are badly coded in the app and could be improved, but I'm not a web developer at Uber...

So I'm asking out of desperation, is there anything I could do to make this app use less resources?

(Xiaomi Redmi 5A - LineageOS 15.1)

Answer (score 1):

So, after some use of this Uber app, some elements for answering:

- The app keeps the screen on, so I can improve the situation by turning off the screen when I don't need it.
- I'm considering upgrading to a phone with a more energy-efficient CPU (from 28 nm to 12 nm), it should help a bit.
- I'm having a "lipstick powerbank" plugged in the more possible, to wear it off instead of the phone battery.

I guess that's the best I will be able to achieve…